# PowerMock test Activity onCreate

Tags: android, testing, mockito, powermock

I'm trying to test an `onCreate` method of an android activity.
The activity is named `LoginActivity` and it inherits from `AppCompatActivity`.
The method calls `super.onCreate()` method of the `AppCompatActivity` where it fails deeply inside when calling `getWindow`. It throws not mocked error.

So I tried to suppress the method of the `AppCompatActivity` by doing:

```
Method[] appCompatActivityOnCreateMethods =
        PowerMockito.methods(AppCompatActivity.class, "onCreate");

PowerMockito.suppress(appCompatActivityOnCreateMethods);

loginActivity = spy(new LoginActivity());
```

But it doesn't seem to work. When I call:

```
loginActivity.onCreate(mock(Bundle.class));
```

It still calls the `super.onCreate` method.

I did a `@PrepareForTest()` for `AppCompatActivity` and for my `LoginActivity`

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you did what you wrote, and did not what you did not write, you forgot to use the `PowerMockRunner`. From the [Getting Started Guide](https://github.com/jayway/powermock/wiki/GettingStarted):

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest( { YourClassWithEgStaticMethod.class })
public class YourTestCase {
    ...
}
```

Comment: I did write it too, from what I found its a bug in the 1.6.4 version of power mock that will be fixed in 1.6.5. The bug is that it doesn't suppress protected methods on spies